# To fetch ALTERNATE records from a table.

Tags: sql-server

I have two table emp1 and emp2 and i want to fetch the alternate records from the table like odd and even and 3rd Max Salary of Emp

> table like emp1

```
empno empname empposition
1     abc     Manager
2     cef     Clark
3     xyz     Supervisor
4     pqr     Peon
5     hij     Senior Manager
```

> table like emp2

```
empno empname empsalary
1     abc     25,000
2     cef     15,000
3     xyz     10,000
4     pqr     5,000
5     hij     35,000
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your attempt ie. a query you have written up until this point.

Comment: Please provide an outcome example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i need alternate records from table and also want to 3rd highest  and lowest salary of emp

Comment: u want alternate records or 3rd highest salary or both

Comment: Putting a third table in your question which shows the expected results would probably be far better to show what's being sought after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following, It worked for me.

To fetch even Numbered row:

SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name % 2 = 0

To fetch odd Numbered row:

SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name % 2 = 1

Hope it helps!!

Comment: This will only work for tables having column "number" or "id" something. How about table not having any number column?

Answer (score 2):

Best way to fetch the Odd and Even Rows in SQL Table is done by using RowNumber,

```
Declare @Emp2 Table (empno INT, empname VARCHAR(10), empsalary INT)


INSERT INTO @Emp2 (empno,empname,empsalary) VALUES (1    , 'abc'  ,   25000)
INSERT INTO @Emp2 (empno,empname,empsalary) VALUES (2    , 'cef'  ,   15000)
INSERT INTO @Emp2 (empno,empname,empsalary) VALUES (3    , 'xyz'  ,   10000)
INSERT INTO @Emp2 (empno,empname,empsalary) VALUES (4    , 'pqr'  ,   5000 )
INSERT INTO @Emp2 (empno,empname,empsalary) VALUES (5    , 'hij'  ,   35000)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY empno) AS RowNumber 
            --Row_Number() starts with 1
    FROM @Emp2
) t
WHERE t.RowNumber % 2 = 0 --Even
--WHERE t.RowNumber % 2 = 1 --Odd
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Bellow Queryfor Even Number Employee

```
select empname as Employee,salary as Salary 
 from emp2 
 where empno in (
                 select empno 
                 from emp2 
                 group by empno having empno%2=0
                )
```

Also Use Bellow Query for Odd Number Employee

```
select empname as Employee,salary as Salary 
 from emp2 
 where empno in (
                 select empno 
                 from emp2 
                 group by empno having empno%2 <> 0
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> FOR ODD RECORDS

```
 SELECT * FROM EMP1 INNER JOIN EMP2 ON EMP1.EMPNO=EMP2.EMPNO WHERE (EMP1.empno %2)<> 0
```

> FOR EVEN RECORDS

```
 SELECT * FROM EMP1 INNER JOIN EMP2 ON EMP1.EMPNO=EMP2.EMPNO WHERE (EMP1.empno %2)= 0
```

> FOR THIRD MAX SALARY

```
SELECT TOP 1 EMPSALARY FROM EMP2 WHERE EMPSALARY NOT IN
(SELECT TOP 2 EMPSALARY FROM EMP2 ORDER BY EMPSALARY DESC)
ORDER BY EMPSALARY DESC
```

Comment: Who said that EMPNO's are strictly sequential? And what about equal salaries?

Answer (score 0):

I try this and its worked for me and i hope it will helps you.

(EVEN NUMBERED)

```
select * from emp1 where rowid in (select decode(mod(rownum,2),0,rowid, null) from emp1);
```

(ODD NUMBERED)

```
select * from emp1 where rowid in (select decode(mod(rownum,2),0,null ,rowid) from emp1);
```

3rd MAX salary

```
select distinct empsalary from emp2 e1 where 3 = (select count(distinct empsalary ) from emp2 e2 where e1.empsalary <= e2.empsalary );
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the alternate records from a table you can run this query:

```
select r,empno,empname,empposition from(select rownum r,empno,empname,empposition from emp1) where mod(r,2)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is fecthing odd records in SQL SERVER
Here is `salarytable2`:

```
name    salary
abc 100000
bc  1000000
efg 50000
klm 2000000
```

Here I am using `Row_number()` to get the row number and applying modulus to it to categorize into even or odd records.

```
select * from (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by salary) as rownum from salarytable2) as saltable where saltable.rownum%2 <>0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE_GET_ALTERNATE_RECORDS
AS
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY BOOK_ID) AS [ROW_NUMBER] FROM BOOK 
    )
    SELECT * FROM CTE_GET_ALTERNATE_RECORDS WHERE [ROW_NUMBER]%2=1
--WHERE [ROW_NUMBER]%2=0 For even rows
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch odd records:

```sql
select columnname from (select rowno,columnname from table) where mod(rowno,2)=1;
```

To fetch even records:

```sql
select columnname from (select rowno/columnname from table) where mod(rowno,2)=0;
```